# UITableViewController In Swift Crashes

Tags: uitableview, swift

Currently trying to migrate a Objective-C app to Swift using mixed mode. However, I have hit a brick wall.

The code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class AboutLocationController : UITableViewController {
    override init() {
        super.init(style: .Grouped);
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder);
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.tableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell");
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2;
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell;
        cell.textLabel!.text = "Cell";
        return cell;
    }
}
```

The problem:
When this is run, it crashes with an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) and the exception is indicated on the class AboutLocationController : UITableViewController { line.

Any help would be great.

Cheers

Comment: Can you please paste in the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with the same issue, the following function was missing...

```
private override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String!, bundle nibBundleOrNil: NSBundle!) {
    super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
}
```

Not sure why it's needed as I'm never loading the controller from a nib, but adding it fixes the issue.

Comment: It's an issue because it's the designated initializer for a controller.